# google directory api -> Get phone numer from user.phones[].primary

Tags: api, directory

I use this code to logger successfully log : user fullname and user primaryEmail. 
from property of [AdminDirectory.Users.list](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users)

But I don't understand how I can get the phone user .
The syntax user.phones[].primary doesn't work

```
    function listAllUsers() {
   var pageToken, page;
   do {
    page = AdminDirectory.Users.list({
      domain: 'example.com',
      orderBy: 'givenName',
      maxResults: 100,
      pageToken: pageToken
    });
    var users = page.users;
    if (users) {
      for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
        var user = users[i];
        Logger.log(user.name.fullName, user.primaryEmail,user.phones[].primary);
      }
    } else {
      Logger.log('No users found.');
    }
    pageToken = page.nextPageToken;
  } while (pageToken);
}
```

The parameters user.phones[] doesnt' work see google reference

Comment: "The parameters of"... of what, sorry?  Looks like you submitted your post before completing it.

Comment: The sample question what is the syntax to display phone number in AdminDirectory.Users.list with the example code bellow

Answer (score 1):

You are attempting to access an array (that's what the `[]` indicates), therefore you must specify an index.

If you want to access the `primary` variable of the first value in the `phones` array, then you would use:

```
user.phones[0].primary
```